# Using Sales Force Identity Provider as a Provider for Thinktecture Identity Server

Tags: salesforce, saml, thinktecture-ident-server

I am trying to connect the Thinktecture Identity Server to Sales Force, using the Sales Force Identity provider as a provider for the Thinktecture Identity server.

The information I am lacking is the Entity ID and the ACS URL to enter within the Sales Force Service Provider form.

I hope someone can provide some insight on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Salesforce OOTB only supports SAML-P (protocol) federation.

Thinktecture Identity Server only supports WS Federation.

This article may be of use - [How to configure SSO from Salesforce to SharePoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Configuring-SSO-to-SharePoint) as it shows how to add WS-Fed to Salesforce.